# Ignore User Abort, Ignored by PHP?

Tags: php

Hell all,

I have made use of the following [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).

```
ignore_user_abort(true); set_time_limit(0); session_start();
```

However, when I navigate away from the page which I fireoff an AJAX request, the script stops?

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

In the PHP manual it says:

> PHP will not detect that the user has
>   aborted the connection until an
>   attempt is made to send information to
>   the client. Simply using an echo
>   statement does not guarantee that
>   information is sent, see flush().

It seems to suggest you can use echo and it will just identify that the user has disconnected and it will continue?

Comment: How do you see that the script stops?

Comment: I have a set of SQL script it runs through and it stops half way of creating those scripts. It should create more and as soon as I navigate to another page - I see that it stops creating these files.

Comment: The script (rest.php) that is run from the AJAX GET request (process.php) is the one that stops even though I have the ignore at the top of the script (rest.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP will not detect... until an attemt is made to send information to the client

This sounds to me like: when php can't flush its buffer to the client: stop. So I suggest using `ob_start()` to buffer everyting at the start of the page, you can also implement gzip this way: `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server has a built-in timeout that kills the script?
You should also note that you shouldn't use `echo` in an aborted script, because you have nowhere to send the output.

Comment: @Emil can you have a look at my updated question. Thanks. It seems that echo can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider

Are you sure the user abort is causing the problem?

Have you checked the log to see if there are any errors logged.?

Does your server kill the script regardless of the the script itself?

Is the ajax call even being made? I assume it runs when the user navigates away.

You can use wireshark to watch the traffic between your browser and the webserver to make sure what you think is happening is actually happening.

DC